# Error: redefinition of random and related compiler errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct {
    double x;
    float yellow;
    double number;

}budget;
struct budget random;    //error: redefinition of random

void color(dollar){

    random.number = random.x - dollar; //error member referance has a base type long(void)not a structure or union.

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){


   random.x = 10;//error member referance has a base type long(void)not a structure or union.
   random.yellow = 1.4;//error member referance has a base type long(void)not a structure orunion
   int dollar = 4; 
   color(newNumber); use of undeclared variable new number.

   NSLog(@"the total budget is %.2f", random.number); //error member referance has a base type long(void)not a structure or union.

   return 0 ;
}
```

I was following a video tutorial on Objective-C: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsXivZEU9rc&list=SP54515103C712A53D&index=19, and I've tried everything I could think of, but this code will not return `random.number` total, which would be `random.x-dollar` as is stated in the function `color()`. I then called `color()` in `main` and renamed its argument, which should copy `dollar` in the function and return it, but it's not. What's going on?

Comment: Despite NSLog, what of that is Objective-C? I only see standard C there.

Comment: `Struct budget random;` Does not make sence, I think. Although I do not see the redefinition of random. Get rid of `struct`; And `newNumber`acually is undeclared.

Comment: i solved it,in global when i declared a struct i had to put typedef infront of it,then when i declared in main i have to put typedef before the struct again, and as for the function color() in main, the argument inside the ()must have a value and be initlized in main so i put int dollars=4; then called the function color(dollars). then i went back into the global where i declared color and just initialized (newnumber) or any variable because color(dollars) copy dollar value an just plug it in on top. then for the statemnt inside color(new) i could have used any value in the declared struct.

Comment: wonder y i have to keep putting typedef before the structs everytime i declare them in a new class

Comment: That depends on whether you just declare a structure and in an instant declare the associated varialbe or you declare a type that you may want to reuse later for variables of the same type.

Comment: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` is not C; it is Objective-C.  The problem is likely to be that `random()` is a method or function declared via the `#import` and therefore the global variable is deemed to be redefining the name `random()`. As a workaround, rename the variable `random` to something else and check that the error goes away.

Answer (score 2):

I can't view the video because of work, but you are redefining 'random'. Try replacing your variable "random" with another name. The rest of the errors are simply cascading from the first one (your redefinition of random).

Comment: k ill try that. also @herman, if i declare a struct as global then call it again in main, ill get like a warning yellow sign in xcode to put in the struct before budget. idk y it does that, the file type is foundation or its importing from foundation. if u guys could give me some help, on some good objective-c tutorias that would be nice.websites other than apple websites, those i know.